# Broken jQuery Tab Switcher

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

**Liver Demo:** https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/Replaced-With-Divs.html

**jQuery Tab Switch Code** *ignore lines 2-6*

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-300px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    $('#tab-content div:last').show();

    $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').click(function() {
        $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass("current");
        $(this).find('li').addClass("current");
        $('#tab-content div').hide();

        var indexer = $(this).index(); //gets the current index of (this) which is #nav li
        $('#tab-content div:eq(' + indexer + ')').fadeIn(); //uses whatever index the link has to open the corresponding box 
    });
});
```

I am having trouble implementing a jQuery tab switch into my website:

```
"$(this).find('li').addClass("current");"
```

is used to find 'a', however I need it to change the class of the li and not the a.

The only tab switch content which is showing is part of the second one from the top and not all of it. I am just very confused at this moment in time and could really do with some help.

---

**Update:**

```
    $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass("current");

Seems to be removing the class upon clicking, however

    $(this).find('li').addClass("current");

Does not seem to add the class to the new clicked tab.

    $("#tab-3").toggle(function () {
        // $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({right:'-976px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft: '976px'}, 1000).addClass('current');
    }, function () {
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({right:'670px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });

I am trying to apply the above to the 'Hide This' tab, so when you click on it, it move further right out of view and recliick to show.

Full Script So Far:
$(function () {
    $("#tab-3").toggle(function () {
        // $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({right:'-976px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft: '976px'}, 1000).addClass('current');
    }, function () {
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({right:'670px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    $('#tab-content div:last').show();

    $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').click(function() {
        $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass("current");
        $(this).find('li').addClass("current");
        $('#tab-content div').hide();
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
        $('#tab-content div' + href).fadeIn().find('*').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check my edits, you still don't have some of the latest changes. Also the toggle function does not work as there is no element with an id of tab-3! You need to give the li element an id of tab-3.

Comment: @Aydin Hassan I have now given the li an id of tab-3, however there is still no movement. I have gone through what you have said and I cannot work out what I am doing wrong exactly. Live version is now updated. Best Regards, Tim

Comment: @Aydin Hassan I don't know what I just did, however it is now almost working correctly. My 'overflow:hidden; is not working and I would like #tab-3 not to switch the tab.

Comment: Yeah just noticed the animation is working, the current class isn't working because you haven't copied my code properly: `$(this).find('li').addClass("current");` should be `$(this).addClass("current");`

Comment: Brilliant! Now I just need to figure out why my overflow is showing... Oh and to edit the name from 'Hide this' to 'Show This'. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.find('li')`.

You don't need that as the click event is fired on the li element. So `$(this)` IS the li element.

Then you do:

```
$('#Info-Side-Tabs li').click(function() {
    $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
    $('#tab-content div' + href).fadeIn()
});
```

That works for me, other than there being no "#tab2" and "#tab3" content divs.
The index code wouldnt work because the index is numerical and you are trying to match a content div, it won't match because the divs have string id's

**Edit**

You can show all child elements using the following:

`$('#tab-content div' + href).fadeIn().find('*').show();`

**Edit 2**

The `:last` selector is finding the deepest div element inside `#tab-content` and showing it, which is: `<div id="Social-Fun" style="display: none;">`

That's why you don't see anything.

You could add a class to each div, something like `class='country'` and then you could do:

`$('#tab-content div.country').last().show()`

Comment: you have got it working more than I could, however the title and image for the 'main' tab is now showing. The title of 'Australia' with it's flag. I have just noticed that any div inside of this is not showing up, so id="Social-Fun" is not showing and div class="Title" is not either. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Also @Aydin Hassan I don't suppose you're able to look over my animate for the 'Hide This' tab? I think this is conflicting with this tab switch, only if it's not too off topic. Thanks

Comment: The child elements should show now, I'm not sure what you mean about the title and image on the main tab?

Comment: It seems to hide any div's inside of #tab-content regardless of where they are and the 'current' class does not seem to be switching, it removes but does not add it elsewhere. The live version has been updated.

Comment: Updated again - the current class should be added correctly now

Comment: Sorry, your last messaged appeared upon submitting mine. I have updated the live version again, of which results in #Australia now showing #Social-Fun but not .Title. I also think my attempt of making one of the tabs slide the content out of view might be conflicting?

Comment: Bingo! A message appeared again upon submitting my last message. As far as I'm concerned, you've earned question thick thing. If you can't help with the tabs, you might have already messaged and I'll see it upon submitting again, I'll just make another question after playing around. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: $('#tab-content div:last').show(); no longer seems to start on load at the last, which should be #Australia, it loads with nothing I presume it's loading the first one?

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't working now, update your question with some more information and point out which code isn't working and I'll have a look

Comment: I did what you said in your new edit, however it appears to not load the full tab content until you click on it and . I have updated the live version. Also the 'current' is not switching.